# Laravel Route pass additional variables

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, routes

I have a user controller which returns users list, each user belongs to different group.

> ex:- $groups = ['student_users' => 1, 'teacher_users' => 2, .....]

I can create routes such as below to access them

```
Route::get('users/{id}', [
        'as'            =>  'user',
        'uses'          =>  'Admin\UserController@listUser'
    ]);
```

But i want to create more user friendly or seo friendly say like this

```
Route::get('users/student', [
        'as'            =>  'student',
        'uses'          =>  'Admin\UserController@listUser'
    ]);

Route::get('users/teacher', [
        'as'            =>  'teacher',
        'uses'          =>  'Admin\UserController@listUser'
    ]);
Route::get('users', [
        'as'            =>  'student',
        'uses'          =>  'Admin\UserController@listUser'
    ]);//by default shows students list.
```

And i want to pass the id via route not via url. Whats the best way to do it.

Comment: `Admin\UserController@listUser@user_id` that will be argument of `listUser` method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

do as following

```
Route::get('users/student', [
    'as'            =>  'student',
    'type'          =>  'student',
    'uses'          =>  'Admin\UserController@listUser'
]);
```

in controller you can get `type` as below

```
public function listUser(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)

   $action = $request->route()->getAction();
   dd($action['type']); 
}
```

`type` is just an example. You can pass any variable.

I hope it helps.